# Convert HTML content to plain text in HTML supported email

Tags: html, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am using Build Failure Analyzer Jenkins plugin, I define failure cause for build failure.

Now I want to store failure cause output and send it in email. Hence I've following in my pipeline which uses email extension plugin -

```
 post {  
    failure {
        script {   
           def subject = "${env.JOB_NAME} - Build # ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
           def buildFailure = tm('${BUILD_FAILURE_ANALYZER}')

    emailext attachLog: false,
        body:  buildFailure,
        subject: subject,
        to: "testemail@test.com"
        }
}
```

In email extension configuration in Jenkins, if `Default Content Type` has value `Plain text (text\html)`, I get content like following in email -

```
Identified problems:
* Code compilation failed Actions:
 1. Please click on below indication link to know the compilation failure
 2. Please resolve compilation errors
  * Indication 1:
    <http://localhost:9090//job/EmailPipelineCopy/15/consoleFull#1856183693ffa56480-b39d-4982-9c6e-524135dff05e>
```

which is what I expect but if I set `Default Content Type` to `HTML (text\html)`, in email I get content like -

```
Identified problems: * Code compilation failed Actions: 1. Please click on below indication link to know the compilation failure
```

2. Please resolve compilation errors * Indication 1:

which is not good display and also links are not available. I need to set `Default Content Type` to `HTML (text\html)` because other contents in email in HTML.

Is there any way we can change this HTML content to text so it'll appear in email with links and proper aligning as it is with `Default Content Type`=`HTML (text\html)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed `<` and `>` characters from the text and surrounded it with `<pre>` tag then HTML treated that text as it is.